# The Subjective Tag

Tags: discussion

Are we going to have it? I know there is a discussion going on in the Meta.SO community about whether or not the Subjective Tag should just be removed.

There it would face considerably more problems, but in our case the site is a lot smaller (only 17 [subjective] questions) and we could end this issue before it starts.

> ## Related
>
> [Should we permanently remove the [subjective] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51627/should-we-permanently-remove-the-subjective-tag)

Comment: Forgot to wiki so others can edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff just posted a blog about this exact topic, that lays out a pretty good case for subjective be banned:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: And to make the point stronger, he says, " **From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.** "

Answer (score 0):

Subjective is fine with me.  They might need to be required as CW seeing as there really isn't a real answer to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think subjective questions are necessary for this SE site. Gaming is a very diverse topic; you will find a lot of questions that begin with "What's the easiest way to..." or "What is the best library for..." etc. I don't think these kinds of questions should be banned. I think the subjectivity inherent in game dev is particularly noticable when dealing with things like storyline and effects. Game development is a very new academic area, so it stands to reason that there just *isn't* a right answer to some of these questions (yet). That said, they still need to be asked.

Comment: This isn't completely about subjective questions. We already deal with a bit of subjectivity. This is about the tag [subjective]. Which has already been nuked.

Comment: It's also that the kinds of questions we want to encourage are different.  "What's the best engine" is a bad question.  "What's an engine that meets my requirements X, Y, and Z" is a better question.