# Which tags are useless or blacklisted?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question covers our list of "bad" tags, tags which don't make sense in general or in the specific context of the site. These include [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags), tags that are redundant with the focus of the site (`game-development`), non-specific tags, and so on.

Note that originally this question was set up as a community-wiki, with one answer per bad tag suggestion. Recently we seemed to have moved to a model where we post individual meta questions for each tag, which seems to foster better discussion. You can still post in this topic if you like.

This list can also cover tag synonym suggestions. For example, [dx11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dx11) should be mapped to [directx11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx11). Note that you can vote on tag synonyms other people propose. For a list of synonyms currently in the system, [go here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest).

## Currently Blacklisted Tags

The tag link pages for each of these should be empty. If you add a new tag here, please preserve the alphabetical ordering for easier browsing. Please link to the discussion that lead to the tag being included on the blacklist for posterity.

- [2d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d-physics) (just use `physics` and/or `2d` instead; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/split-2d-physics-into-2d-and-physics))
- [actions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) (generic, [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2044/is-actions-a-worthwhile-tag))
- [api](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api) (meta-tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/weve-blacklisted-engine-should-we-do-the-same-for-the-other-similar-tags))
- [artifacts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artifacts) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2162/is-the-artifacts-tag-worthwhile))
- [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread/157#157))
- [best-practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread/161#161))
- [buffers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers) (generic; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/remove-buffers-tag))
- [circle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [class](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/whats-the-point-of-the-class-tag))
- [compilation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compilation) (does not add value, [related thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/should-we-blacklist-the-compilation-tag))
- [computer-science](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) (generic, off-topic; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1889/1430))
- [conceptual](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conceptual) (meta-tag; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/are-the-tags-concept-and-conceptual-useful-here))
- [delta](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) (does not add value, [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/suggestion-to-rename-the-tag-delta-to-delta-time))
- [design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/should-the-design-tag-encompass-architecture-and-game-design-questions), [tag renames](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread/167#167))
- [development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread/156#156))
- [engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) (meta tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2391/how-should-we-use-the-engine-tag))
- [environment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment) (too broad; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2341/can-we-please-burn-the-environment-tag))
- [feedback](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback) (too ambiguous; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1857/1430))
- [framework](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) (meta-tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/weve-blacklisted-engine-should-we-do-the-same-for-the-other-similar-tags))
- [free](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) (meta-tag, [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/do-we-really-need-a-free-tag))
- [game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) ([prior decision](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43/the-word-game-in-tags-is-redundant))
- [hexagon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hexagon) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [hobby-development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobby-development) (meta-tag with no value, executive decision based on similarity to [indie](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indie))
- [homework](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) (Another executive decision, it's a meta tag that doesn't describe the *content* of the question.)
- [indie](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indie) (meta-tag with no value, see the [related thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/what-value-does-the-indie-tag-provide))
- [infinite](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite) (too general; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/do-we-really-need-the-infinite-tag))
- [inspector](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspector) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2150/how-should-we-handle-the-inspector-tag-and-unity-tags))
- [language-agnostic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) (Executive decision, this semi-meta tag adds nothing on the content of the question.  Most questions are algorithm or math related, or specifics of a particular language.  This tag is redundant, as any programming/math/algorithm question without a specific language tag is going to be assumed to be language agnostic.)
- [language-choice](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-choice) (Executive decision, all questions tagged this way are a "which technology is best" type, which shouldn't be used anyway.)
- [languages](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/is-the-languages-tag-useful))
- [learning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) (Executive decision, but there's precedence on [other sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102178/blacklist-the-learning-tag))
- [libraries](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/libraries) (meta-tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/weve-blacklisted-engine-should-we-do-the-same-for-the-other-similar-tags))
- [limitations](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limitations) (meta tag; executive decision)
- [middleware](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middleware) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/do-we-need-the-tag-middleware))
- [old-school](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-school) (meta tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2415/do-we-need-the-old-school-tag))
- [opinion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion) ([same as `subjective`](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/the-subjective-tag))
- [pre-processing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-processing) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/is-the-pre-processing-tag-useful))
- [polygon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polygon) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [quads](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quads) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/))
- [rectangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectangle) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [sdk](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sdk) (meta-tag; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/weve-blacklisted-engine-should-we-do-the-same-for-the-other-similar-tags))
- [shape](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shape) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) (too ambiguous; [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/sizing-up-the-size-tag))
- [smooth](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth) (too ambiguous; [related post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1627/1430))
- [subjective](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151/the-subjective-tag))
- [techniques](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techniques) (meta tag or too broad: [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2483/is-the-tag-techniques-useful))
- [tips](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) (another meta tag)
- [triangle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [triangles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangles) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/do-we-need-tags-for-rectangle-circle-triangle-hexagon-and-shape))
- [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) ([discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/the-tag-units-and-us))
- [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) ([used broadly](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/whither-the-update-tag) for content covered by [game-loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-loop) [deployment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) [synchronization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization))
- [surface](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface)(meta-tag: [discussion](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2867/33287))

Note that there's an easy way to link to tags nowadays.  The format is:

```
[tag:TAG_NAME]
```

Comment: I have closed this question because we've reached the point where the scope of the question is too large to effectively manage the proposals or the discussion using the SE format. We have long since switched over to a model of having individual discussions for each blacklist proposal, and simply linking them from this question when a consensus is arrived at. If you would like to propose a tag for the blacklist or discuss the blacklisted state of a tag, please make a dedicated meta thread for the topic.

Answer (score 23):

[development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development)

It's *almost*, but not quite as bad as having the word [game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) in a tag on the "Game Development" Stack Exchange site.  It's somewhat implied that all the questions are either about game development in some fashion.

Personally, I don't see any question on that list that if I was trying to categorize it or search for it would be helped by the inclusion of [development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development).

Comment: Seems to be consensus on this one.  Jeff Atwood went ahead and removed the tag, but I think people with editing power are going to have to keep an eye out to make sure it doesn't get re-added.

Answer (score 15):

[flash-professional](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-professional)

Honestly, I don't understand why there's such a tag. If somebody has a flash-related question, they will tag it [flash](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash). I don't think [flash-professional](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash-professional) does any good for further classifying flash-related questions.

Comment: Blandantly useless, used it in just two questions (one of which is closed, btw): removed it.

Answer (score 14):

[opinion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opinion)

It is synonymous with [subjective](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective)

Comment: **DONE** (a while ago)

Answer (score 14):

[hobby-development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hobby-development)

Is there a significant difference between hobby development and other forms of development? If I have a question about which physics engine I should use or what kind of school I should go to, will the fact that I'm hobbyist developer make a significant difference?

Comment: This feels like a "meta" tag to me (read: useless/unadvised).  You can argue there is slight precedence with the `homework` tag on SO.  However removing tags (as opposed to merging) is pretty difficult and there isn't an easy way to "ban" tags, so this is lower priority to me.

Answer (score 12):

[collision](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision)

Make it a synonym of [collision-detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/collision-detection)

There were two collision detection questions with the tag before I retagged them ([1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/2d-side-scrolling-game-and-walk-over-ground-collision-detection), [2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/collision-resolution)).

Comment: You can vote on them here http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: **Done** (a while ago)

Answer (score 10):

[sound](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) & [audio](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio)

They seem to overlap quite a bit. If no one has any rationale against it, I'll merge.

Comment: If I was asking a question about sound effects I would not use audio, Sound is more appropriate there, "Sound" deals with vibrations through different mediums with physical properties and characteristics like reverb and Doppler effect. Audio would be the output of all that and included stuff like music which is not really classified as just sound. I think they are different enough to keep separate.

Comment: Although I see your point, I think most people would be confused about which one to use, resulting in many cases where each is used incorrectly. Merging these two together could prevent those issues from occurring, which makes somewhat of a case for merging them, at least there are enough tagged questions to provide an easily discernible difference between the two tags.

Comment: Based on how the site seems to actually use the tags, [sound]should either find itself inside [audio], or [sound-effects]. The current ones are actually more of the former, but in some ways a synonym towards the latter seems more appropriate post-fix.

Comment: This seems like something that should be revisited and/or discussed. There's a plethora of [sound] tagged stuff that could fit in one of the two mentioned buckets.

Answer (score 9):

[learning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) & [education](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education)

I don't really see the need for both of these. Can we keep education and merge/remove learning?

Comment: Maybe even make both a synonym for "schooling" or something, so people don't put them in just because they want to learn something from the answer...

Comment: I'd rather make the education tag more specific to talk about schools specifically so there's less overlap.

Answer (score 7):

[best-practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)

Probably a controversial opinion, but [best-practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices), kind of like [discussion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion), [subjective](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective), [poll](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poll), etc. are tags that more often than not describe the *type* of question and not the *content*.  Most [best-practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices) questions are either 1) mistagged, or 2) lists of things to do (i.e. subjective community-wiki questions).

For more discussion: [Are questions about best practices bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16599/are-questions-about-best-practices-bad)

> If that's really what you're after - a practice widely-recognized as "best" that you can adopt as your own, then go for it. All too often though, i see people asking for a "best practice" when what they really want to know is:
>
> > "Given **my** situation, what are the available solutions to **my specific problem**, and which one should **I** choose?"
>
> Note the key difference: if you aren't free to make changes, potentially major, to what you're doing and how you're doing it, then "industry best" is irrelevant - you just need something you can use now. Perhaps it'll happen to be a Best Practice; perhaps it'll merely be the best of a bad set of hacks necessitated by the particular corner you've been painted into. But regardless, the focus has to be on you.

Comment: Jeff weighed in on this tag: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: To me, this tag is less cut-and-dry than `beginner`.  If you just look at the content of our site compared to SO, a lot of the questions are "let me see good examples of X so I can decide how I want to solve my problem".  Which groks with my way of doing things in my professional career as well.  I'm personally on the fence about this tag (even though I suggested it), probably because it isn't as "overused" here.

Comment: I'm going to make a judgement call and say we should remove the tag from questions.

Answer (score 7):

[turn-based-strategy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-based-strategy) (Destruction)

Specifically, I'm advocating its replacement with the tags [turn-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-based) [strategy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy). It probably does not need black-listing, just the initial destruction to remove it from the queue.

Normally I'm a promotor of singular combo tags, but in this scenario I'm actually leaning towards the former. Browsing [strategy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy) shows a lot of questions about the Strategy genre that can be safely abstracted from the game's being real-time versus turn-based. Likewise, [turn-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-based) can be applied to other genres, most predominantly RPG. Those two tags have important meaning to be used on their own as a result, and their combination is literally identical in meaning to the combined tag.

Unlike with what I see on the Gaming Stack Exchange, there seems to be no huge ambiguity as to what "strategy" means - to game developers it applies to the genre. There is [one exception](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8643/is-there-any-simple-game-that-involves-psychological-factors), but it needs a big retag and otherwise does not seem like it should trend dangerously. Most "unit strategy" questions actually properly get tagged with [ai](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai).

---

Turn-based strategy is a much more defined genre compared to, say, turn-based RPGs. You could easily get away with tagging things as RPG without needing to differentiate the different expressions of it, but being turn-based versus real-time is often part of the soul and definition of a strategy game. So a preference to keep [turn-based-strategy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turn-based-strategy) is more than understandable. But if this is the case, then it feels like something should be done about the other two tags instead.

Answer (score 6):

[beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner)

First off, it's probably off-topic as this site is supposed to be for "professional and amateur game developers."  It's also subjective and localized to the person asking the question.  It is also indicative that a lot of the questions tagged with [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) are also tagged with [tutorials](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials).  It's almost redundant.

I'm not really sure of the purpose of that tag.  Maybe there's some value in that beginners *might* be able to search through the [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner) tagged questions to find some good starting points, but they would just be as likely to find things under [tutorials](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials).

---

*edit*: It's also now banned on the trilogy sites: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: I disagree - I think it could be quite useful. In the same way that a homework tag is encouraged (as it gives context to those answering the question about how to construct their answer to best explain it to the asker), tagging as beginner will help those answering target their answer better. As far as being off-topic, I would think that an amateur game developer could be a beginner.

In terms of searching for beginner-tagged answers, it's not so useful, but then neither is the (encouraged) homework tag.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say that `homework` is *encouraged* on SO.  It's mostly just to satisfy the people who think that homework shouldn't belong there so they can filter it out easily.  Also, there's a key difference from `homework` since beginner is subjective to the person, not an absolute.  A tutorial is a tutorial.  Something that's a *beginner* task to one person isn't necessarily a beginner task to another.

Comment: I think it's useful. If someone tags it as beginner, it indicates that they're looking for a more basic answer. I mean, a topic about how to store game entities for a beginner wouldn't require a long post about optimizations that could possibly have an effect due to the way something is O(log n) over the fact something else is O(n). Rather, they would just want to know that 'x is probably better to use, because it's faster [at O(log n) speed].

Comment: Before @TheCommunistDuck commented I was all for this being considered useless. While in general, it is fluff. It can be **VERY** useful for making sure that our answers help the person asking the question. Difficulty is variable in Game Development, this would make the professionals among us be able to say I'm not interested in giving the "for dummies" version of the answer to that. And help with their signal/noise ratio.

Comment: Here's a discussion on meta-tags on another new SE site which I think sums up my opinions on the subject: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/434/please-zap-the-meta-tags-and-dependent-tags.  Yes, question difficulty is variable, and scope is variable, but at the end of the day we're trying to find **answers** to **problems**, and it shouldn't matter the level of the problem or the level of the asker in order to get to a solution.

Comment: Jeff weighed in on this tag: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 6):

[design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design)

Based on the conversation here: [Should the "design" tag encompass architecture AND game design questions?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/should-the-design-tag-encompass-architecture-and-game-design-questions), *design* is too ambiguous a term in game development.  It can refer to the art side of things (i.e. character design), the game design side of things (or a subset of that, level design), or the engine design side of things.

I went through and renamed the existing [design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) to [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design), and retagged [design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) questions that were talking about engine design to [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) (which may also be due for a rename to have the word [engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) in it).

Note that this tag (at the time of this writing) doesn't exist, but I wanted to put this answer in this question anyway for safe keeping.

Answer (score 6):

[jobs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jobs) & [career](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) (Synonym)

As opposed to [this group](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread/409#409), this pair deals with the variety of occupations in the game development world, as well as advice on getting those jobs. Between the two tags, there aren't really any distinguishing factors that I can find.

Comment: And [tag:hiring]

Answer (score 5):

[2d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d-physics)

A bit more subjective, but the distinction between 2D physics and just [physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) probably isn't worth making.

<sub>Plus the programmer in me hates tags that start with a number.  Variables aren't supposed to start with a number.</sub>

Comment: [2d] [physics] would be just as good.

Comment: hmm, 2d-physics (which also ties into things like mario's physics) has a pretty different connotation to me than normal old physics, which is implicitly 3D to a professional game developer. I assume that is why they are distinct.

Comment: Conceptually, 2D physics are a different beast in quite many ways. For example: rotation (and rotational energy) works very differently, concepts like density have different units (kg/m^2 vs. kg/m^3 for the 3D variant) and consequently the laws of physics are quite different as well. The solutions to Navier-Stokes equations (for fluid dynamics; those are generic differential equations theoretically working on any number of dimensions) even look differently.

Answer (score 5):

[graphics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics)

While looking at some retagging I added a graphics tag before realizing it was overloaded and questioning my decision. It refers to both 3d rendering programming (which [rendering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendering) would seem to cover better) and [art](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/art), and [graphics-programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-programming) is on a few questions as well. Does the [graphics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag by itself make any sense?

Comment: I agree. The meaning, like `design`, is overloaded. It almost seems like `graphics-programming` and `rendering` are very similar as well, but I'm not sure enough of they should be synonyms yet.

Answer (score 5):

[learning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)

Another "meta-tag" that describes the *type* of question instead of the *content*.  SE sites aren't a discussion board, and questions with this tag (usually) are the kinds of questions that don't have a point.

It's kind of like [beginner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner).

Comment: Can't it be viewed as almost exactly the same as beginner? If you want to learn about X, Y, and Z to increase your knowledge, then you must be a beginner at X, Y, and Z.

Comment: I'm going to make an executive decision to remove this tag.

Answer (score 5):

[generated](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generated)

I'm not sure what this tag is supposed to mean.  Perhaps it's mostly a synonym for [procedural-generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedural-generation)?

Comment: There is "generation" other than procedural, such as automatically generated code, but it's still extremely general (after all, wasn't everything generated by SOMETHING?) and doesn't tell potential answerers anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

[units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) is ambiguous as users have asked questions tagged with it that are both about entities (i.e. enemy units) and measurements (e.g. unit conversion).

I also believe it doesn't exactly add much in the way of filtering (i.e. searching for questions that are about units in games (usually contained into a much more major category e.g. strategy games where one expects to find units) and units in physics (physics here is a tag that's enough)).

I recommend deletion.

Answer (score 4):

[languages](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) & [language-choice](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-choice)

- I think these should be merged under [languages](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages).
- I think [languages](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) should also link to all the language specific tags (although this will require a moderate amount of upkeep)

Comment: I'd almost rather obliterate the `languages` tag.  It's also slightly vague with the localization-related question. It really doesn't add anything to the existing questions.

Answer (score 4):

[infinite](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite)

Not sure what this tag really means.  It's been used 8 times: half of them are asking the same question about an infinite scrolling background; the other half are asking a variation about an infinite scrolling level that's has a procedural component.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a need for tags like [3d-engines](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-engines) when you could just combine the [3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d) and [engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engine) tags? This would ensure that anyone interested in engines wouldn't have to search through engine, 2d engine, 3d engine, xxx engine, etc.

Comment: I think 3d and 2d game engines are sufficiently different that I do not think they should be merged.

Comment: In that case, why don't we remove the generic engine tag, and require people to specify the kind of engine?

Comment: Not everything relating to an engine is related to graphics.

Comment: @Tetrad, agreed, but we also have engine architecture, physics engine, etc. tags, so wouldn't it be better to break the engine tag into more specific tags, rather than having a generic tag and a fair amount of specific tags?

Comment: Similar: [tag:2d-physics] == [tag:2d], [tag:physics]?

Answer (score 3):

[project-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) & [management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)

Unless there's sound rationale against it, these should probably be merged.

Comment: There are a couple of `management` questions that aren't project-related.  Like http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/937/managing-a-complex-game-storyline-or-quests-system.  I don't think they should be synonyms, but retagging some of the questions that *should* be `project-management` to be more specific sounds good to me.  Feel free to do that.

Comment: For the question you referenced, I don't see it being so much a "management" related as it is a data structures (how do I store this type of data?) question.

Answer (score 3):

[game-industry](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-industry) & [business](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) (Synonym)

Deals with game development as a business, usually for corporate matters such as profitability and legality. Game industry is the business this site deals with, and the questions under both tags cover mostly the same ground.

Comment: I don't agree with this, but mainly because I think `game-industry` as a tag should go away.  Like you said, the game industry is the business the site deals with, so it should probably be implicit.  I don't think any questions with that tag really describes the *content* of the question.  Some of them probably should be tagged with `business`, though.

Comment: @Tetrad So, probably have to manually sift them, but assume that our main tag for "corporate concerns" will be [business], then?

Comment: Or something similar to it, yes.

Answer (score 3):

[game-component](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-component) and [component-based](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-based)

They're both about the same thing.

Comment: A majority of the [tag:game-component] ones seem to be dealing more with specific XNA components than the concept of writing a component-based system, though.  Maybe component-based could be renamed to something else.

Answer (score 3):

[time-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-management) seems to be ambiguous.

About kill cams: [Handling game states like Braid's timeshift or Shooter's Killcam](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/handling-game-states-like-braids-timeshift-or-shooters-killcam)

About slow-motion: [Easiest Way To Implement "Slow Motion" and variable game speed in XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25789/easiest-way-to-implement-slow-motion-and-variable-game-speed-in-xna)

About update speed: [Stuck at enemy movement](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23193/stuck-at-enemy-movement)

About time-travelling gameplay: [How to implement time traveling into a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/how-to-implement-time-traveling-into-a-game)

About time zones: [What time to display in text messages in multiplayer game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12316/what-time-to-display-in-text-messages-in-multiplayer-game)

About software design: [Splitting a tetris game apart - where to put time-management?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/splitting-a-tetris-game-apart-where-to-put-time-management)

The last one is actually the only one to mention "time management" in the question, but I'm not sure it is actually a *thing* in the way the asker is using it: a software component.

Comment: If you sort by date, you'll notice the (IMO useful) original intent of this tag - production issues of scheduling people over time, not code.

Comment: I went through the questions in [tag:time-management] that were unrelated to time management, and generally replaced them with either [tag:timing] or [tag:time-travel] (a tag I created just for this; apparently we didn't have one before). The [tag:time-travel] tag might be better named _time control_, since slowing down time isn't exactly time travel, but time travel is the more well-known name. Also I added a tag wiki for [tag:time-management] to explain what it actually is.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig Yes, that sounds right. I should have included one of those questions in the above list as well.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Good solution. I'll keep an eye on it as well.

Answer (score 3):

[logic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)

Seems more like a meta tag, and a pretty bad one at that.

One popular use of the tag is as a synonym for "reasoning" or "method", e.g. "Whats the logic behind XYZ?" but you wouldn't use [reasoning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reasoning) would you?

Another popular use is part of "game logic", as opposed to things like rendering, and the separation thereof. Analogous to "business logic" in software. But then it's better served by tags like [architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) or [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming).

Other times it's a synonym for [ai](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) or [algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), which just shows how uselessly broad this tag is.

Of course there is a proper thing called logic in math and philosophy, and is perhaps the right tag to use if someone were asking a question about making a logic puzzle game. I haven't checked if any of the tagged questions fall under this case. It seems doubtful, and in any case this might be better served by a tag like [formal-logic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formal-logic).

Comment: I agree with the conclusion that it's probably a meta-tag. 81 questions is a lot though (there's no "obliterate a tag" mechanism, so it has to be removed manually). I would recommend going through the tagged questions and removing or re-tagging as appropriate. I won't be able to get to all of them myself in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 2):

[assets](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assets) & [resources](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) (Synonym)

With a [couple](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/useful-resources-for-beginning-ai) [exceptions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/game-development-blogs), the latter seems to refer to the same asset management and handling that the former tag covers. I think it may be useful to make these two the same for the more common scenario, while leaving tags on the non-asset posts to refer to what they are resources for (such as "ai" in the first example).

Comment: I'd almost want to just nuke the `resources` tag since it's pretty vague, but in lieu of that I pretty much agree with the synonym.  When used in the exceptional cases you linked to, it's pretty much a meta tag and should just go away.

Answer (score 2):

[programing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programing)
This is just misspelled programming, for which there is already a tag.

Edit: This should be deleted, not made into a synonym.

Comment: I don't think we should make synonyms for misspellings.  I fixed the one case where it was spelled wrong.

Answer (score 2):

[uvw-mapping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uvw-mapping)

It should be a synonym of [uv-mapping](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uv-mapping), as UVW-Mapping is a small subset of that, and is covered in the tag wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[smooth](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth)

The term is hardly ever descriptive without other words nearby (surface, movement, edge, etc).

It can't be used on it's own.

There are no experts in general "smoothness" area.

Comment: I should have finally gotten around to removing all of these.

Answer (score 2):

[procedural](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedural) should be replaced by [procedural-generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedural-generation)

[procedural-generation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/procedural-generation) has a lot more usage and a much better wiki entry and, as far as I can tell, both tags are being used to mean the exact same thing

Answer (score 1):

[directx](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx), [directx9](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx9), [directx10](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx10), [directx11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx11), [direct3d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct3d), [direct3d11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct3d11)

Do we merge all of these under DirectX or do we require that people specify the version of DirectX they are using? Either way, we need to come up with a solution that can be applied to all "versionable" tags.

Comment: Are you suggesting merging to a single 'DirectX' tag? The DirectX versions are significantly different in places so having the number there is a good thing. People often tag questions as DirectX that could be more accurately tagged as Direct3D questions BUT 95% of the time someone says DirectX, they mean Direct3D and for this reason I think we should drop the Direct3D tags and go with numbered DirectX tags (i.e. DirectX, DirectX 9, DirectX 10, DirectX 11). However users may often tag questions as 'Direct3D N' so retagging would be frequent...

Comment: Some questions tagged with a specific DirectX version really apply to any version (or a broad range of versions) of DirectX, but it's up to you taggers to determine if it should remain particular to a version or changed to 'DirectX'.

Comment: The separate versions should stay separate.  The precedence is that questions that are non-version-specific should use the base tag and specific version questions use the more specific system.  There is no hierarchy system for tags and I don't think there ever will be, so merging the versions will be a mistake.  That being said, I'm open to the idea of merging Direct3D* with DirectX*.

Comment: **DONE** (not merging version specific, but merging direct3d into directx) Maybe that'll bite us in the ass later with the people talking about the nuances between the two, but for now I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[minecraft](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is too localized. Replace it with something like:

- [boxvoxel](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boxvoxel) or [boxworld](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boxworld) (add [minecraft](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) as a synonym)
- and introduce [minecraft-mod](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mod)

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the synonyms.  I think [tag:minecraft] reads a lot better than your suggestions.  It's also what more people are likely going to search for and internally categorize as.  I don't necessarily have a problem with the idea of a minecraft-mod tag, but it begs the question if we're going to make a separate -mod tag for any question asking about mods for a specific game.

Comment: @Tetrad thanks. I think the mod tag would generally be on a popularity-basis: if you start getting a few questions about modding a certain game make a tag for (which means I don't think minecraft-mod qualifies).

Answer (score 1):

[easing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/easing) is confusing and has two questions tagged with it, which both deal with the same relatively localised subject of smooth [interpolation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) between two points in space.

Synonym? Delete?

Comment: I suspect this is because easing is part of tweening, what Flash/Actionscript calls location interpolation.  AFAIK interpolation in AS deals specifically with colors.  Still, it would be nice to gently guide AS3-only developers to the industry standard usage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that [maps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) and [levels](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levels) generally mean the same thing, except in the case where "levels" refers to "character level" or something like that.

Both are generally really vague anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[feedback](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feedback)

Not many tagged questions (16), here are what it's being used for:

- Feedback from players (alternative: [community-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-management))
- Force feedback (alternative: [input](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input))
- Transform feedback (alternative: [opengl](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl))
- A meta-tag for getting feedback from this site (please respond)

I suggest removing this tag entirely.

Comment: Tag obliterated.

Answer (score 1):

[computer-science](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science)

Not used much, but all questions belong to two categories:

- Should be using [algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) instead, or not at all
- Not game dev related (i.e. "computer science degree")

So I suggest removing this tag, and maybe replacing some instances of it with [algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm).

Comment: It's been nuked.

Answer (score 0):

[game-mechanics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics) really feels like a synonym of [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design).  There's a [high correlation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-mechanics+game-design) between the two tags

Answer (score -1):

Not a main site tag, but a meta tag, but vague nonetheless.

[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)

[Discussion.](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2153/83207)

**TL;DR**: If your question isn't specific, why are you asking in the first place?

Answer (score -2):

[networking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) & [client-server](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-server)

I think these should be merged under networking, seeing as how the client-server model is a form of distributed computing.

Comment: Not all networking is client-server, though.  "Is a" isn't a good reason for tag merging.

Comment: I don't see what the benefit of having client-server is, when we have networking. If you look through the client-server questions, although they mention the words "client" and "server", most are not client-server model specific, so having them tagged as such is fairly misleading.