# Can community moderators be given permission to enable software-enforced blacklisting of tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

In [the "useless tags" thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread) we've identified several tags that we'd like to avoid, such as [design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design). However nothing prevents users from actually using those blacklisted tags, which creates something of a constant maintainability issue for us. Including a "this is a blacklisted tag" note in the tag wiki (as has been done for [best-practices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices)) might help in some cases, but not all. New users are also unlikely to find the meta discussion on undesirable tags.

In chat, Noctrine mentioned to me that a feature for disabling a tag entirely, preventing it from being used, does exist but is not available to "regular" moderators or general users (only to SE superusers or some such) -- I was hoping it might be possible to allow our moderators access to this feature so that we can keep our tag database more meaningful will less effort.

Comment: [On Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61354/allow-10k-users-to-vote-on-suggested-blacklist-tags/61371#61371 "Albeit, in an answer..."), we're also pushing for this suggestion. We don't have a full-fledged feature request post outside of that answer, but please consider upvoting it to show support for this idea.