# What value does the "indie" tag provide?

Tags: discussion, tags

As of this writing, 69 questions are tagged [`indie`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indie).

What value does this tag provide (if any), and what guidelines should we provide in its wiki to encourage correct use?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not likely to recommend a 5,000$ per seat software license to someone with an indie tag on their question, but I might otherwise.

Comment: That's okay, because questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic anyway. Even disregarding that, if price or license classification (after all, some software packages offer difference licenses based on income tiers, et cetera) are relevant to the question they should be described by the question; the "indie" tag doesn't add that information since the definition of "indie" is broad. Tags are about searchability and should be used mainly for that, not for scoping the question.

Comment: I didn't quite mean a software recommendation. More a question which would be answered by a certain tool/software/codec/etc.

Comment: I know, but I still think if the asker is price-sensitive it should be in the question; the tag doesn't add sufficient information, because [indie developers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_indie_game_developers) have a broad range of purchasing power (and that's list is *hardly* exhaustive or accurate). You can probably safely assume most people here can't afford several-thousand-dollar products, since the overwhelming majority of active participants here are not representing large professional interests.

Comment: It was an example to show that it has _some_ purpose, not commenting on if that purpose was directly useful here (hence this being a comment, not an answer). That said, the list is completely ridiculous ... it's like having a list of devs with beards. 5,000$ is just a hyperbolic example, that much should have been obvious. The workflow of most indie developers isn't going to be comparable to that of most game developers working on professional interests of _any_ size.I don't know how useful it is to debate that unless you're worried about the semantics of the term (which is equally pointless).

Comment: I agree, it's not a worthwhile debate; I just pointed out the list *because* it's such a pointless and arbitrary list and serves to underscore how pointless and arbitrary the definition of "indie" itself could be.

Comment: "The workflow of most indie developers isn't going to be comparable to that of most game developers working on professional interests of any size" is hardly arbitrary. That's why I say you might argue over the _semantics_ of the term, but it's not an entirely useless term, that list is just using it in an embarrassingly nonsensical and useless way...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think this tag provides any useful information, and we should remove it.

`indie` is a meta-tag, and describes more the context of the problem rather than the problem itself, which doesn't offer enough improved search-ability to warrant the consumption of an entire tag slot on a question.

Further, the overwhelming majority of questions asked on this site are from non-professional or hobby developers, such that the `indie` tag is actually applicable to all questions. Therefore, like `game-development`, it's not a valid tag.

Comment: +1. This aligns with [StackExchange's official stance on meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: I have eliminated the tag from all questions (manually, because apparently StackExchange thinks bulk-tag-removal features are not something we should be allowed to have).

Comment: For future reference, I think [the good folks at SO have implemented one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254926/improved-automated-burnination). There is also a [tag-removal (aka 'burnination') script out there](http://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit).

Comment: Yes, I know developers and CMs can do it, but that's obnoxious and neuters some of the community's ability to manage itself.