# Can we prevent the change of post order when moderators are editing meta info?

Tags: feature-request, editing

I have noticed a great wave of editings by Admins recently. Some are from realy old posts and just few things like remove/add of tags.

This is a little unfair with new posts, because that changes are rising theirs posts to the first page of the site and hiding the questions that may need more attention.

If it's not possible to prevent that posts to arise to the first page, at least the admins could have a limite of that kind of editing per day. What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These kinds of [mass editing events](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/what-value-does-the-indie-tag-provide?cb=1) are rare. There isn't a way for us to edit these questions without rising to the top of the active list. If you're interested in seeing the newest questions, I suggest you sort your question list by "Newest" instead of "Active":

[image]

This is how I typically view the main page, so I can address the newest questions.

The "Active" sorting will always be subject to disruption from anyone editing questions, not just moderators.