# Remove buffers tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the [buffers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers) tag from what I can see there are only [5 questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers?sort=active&pageSize=15): 4 are on the subject of OpenGL while the other is DirectX.

To me [buffers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buffers) is ambiguous and doesn't bring anything to a question. It can mean anything and only has a meaning when used in conjunction with something like [opengl](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with this. I'll delete these tags.