# Split [2d-physics] into [2d] and [physics]

Tags: discussion, tags

[2d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d-physics)?

[image: MINDBENDING GIF YES]!

[2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d) [physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)!!

[Noctrine proposed this in a 2010 comment](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted#comment201_160)—some approval, no action.

I think the combined tag adds no extra value. Any reasons to keep it?

Comment: ++ the gif for making it easier to understand visually. http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdA5J.gif

Comment: I've replaced `2d-physics` with `physics` everywhere. This may have caused the `2d` aspect of the tag to get lost, but I consider that a minor issue for the old questions. Manually editing 408 questions isn't something I was keen on doing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think we should get rid of [2d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d-physics).

I don't like the idea of "combined tags" like this, in general, as it just sets precedents for combining two concepts that are really orthogonal as far as the purpose of tags goes. Should we then have [opengl-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl-physics) for doing physics using GPGPU techniques via OpenGL? Should we have [d3d-xinput](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d3d-xinput) for a game that uses XInput and D3D at the same time? These would be absurd, and so is [2d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d-physics).

There are good arguments to be had that 2D physics can afford some fundamental simplifications and thus has a lot of conceptual difference from 3D physics. But the point of tags is not to sum up the whole of a topic in 32 characters or less, it's to provide a classification mechanism useful for searching and filtering questions. "Combined tags" actively detract from that use-case by requiring more tag inputs to filtering and searching UI. Whether or not the nuances of the differences between 2D and 3D physics math and simulation should be apparent from the question text itself, not the tags.

Besides, we don't have [3d-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d-physics).

(Note that by "combined tags" I don't mean "tags with a hyphen," I mean tags composed of two or more sub-tags which are themselves valid for the site. [2d](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2d) and [physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) are both valid sub-tags, but [rope-physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rope-physics) is acceptable because [rope](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rope) isn't a thing. I'm not entirely convinced dimensionality is a useful tag on it's own, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: I have a strange sense of *deja vu* that I've asked you this before, but do moderators have mass stealth tag-morphing superpowers? Writing an edit script that bumps all 400 questions to the front page would probably make me some enemies. :)

Comment: We can mass-rename or mass-merge. I can't mass-delete. My plan here is to simply merge 2d-physics to physics and ignore the 2D tag.