# Why is the mmorpg tag a synonym for mmo?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just because most mmo's are rpg's it doesn't have to mean you can't have mmofps or mmorts.

When I select [mmo](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmo) I expect to see networking related questions and when I click on [mmorpg](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mmorpg) I expect to see questions specific to this genre of games.

Actually we have a mmorts tag, so why not allow for a separate mmorpg tag?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `mmorpg` versus `mmofps` is a worthwhile categorization, personally. I'd say that `mmorts` should also be made a synonym of `mmo`.

These games fall into two broad categories: the MMO aspects thereof, and the "suffix" aspects thereof (RPG, FPS, RTS, cooking simulation, what have you). I believe application of the relevant tags `mmo` and `rpg` will appropriately organize the question for searches and for categorization into domain expertise, and there is no need for us to generate or maintain the full set of pairwise permutations.

It is true that there are subsets of the discipline of producing an MMORPG verus and MMOFPS that may be *specific* to that particular genre category, but I don't believe the breadth of that specific area is large enough to justify an entirely unique tag. Rather, the question itself should call out it's specific nature and that should be sufficient.

By creating tags specifically for each of these sub-genres, I also think we impair their visibility, as users who consider themselves domain experts in the "MMO" area or the "FPS" area may not see questions that they would *otherwise* be able to provide useful input on. It similarly further reduces the chance for an asker to miscategorize their question as an `mmorts` question (because that's what they think they are building) when the actual question is really more to do with RTS mechanics in general or large-scale network synchronization, et cetera.

Further, this fits our already established precedent of avoiding combination tags, [as we chose to do with `2d-physics` recently](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/split-2d-physics-into-2d-and-physics), for example.

Tags should be about aiding, searchability, they should not (and cannot reasonably) be able encoding every detail of a question. In this case I don't (yet) see a useful reason to bloat the tag spectrum with inclusion of these particular details.

Comment: Then is there a way to remove mmorpg and mmorts tags and suggest using the separate tags? Since combined tags aren't really useful...

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have great tools to "teach" users about proper tagging, beyond setting up synonyms; and we can't set up synonyms that map one tag to multiple. We can't even actually blacklist a tag (not that it is relevant to this discussion). :( It would be interesting to have, though. The best we could do is map `mmofps` and `mmorts` to `mmo` and hope the user notices and adds the appropriate `fps` or `rts` tag.