# Suggestion to rename the tag 'delta' to 'delta-time'

Tags: discussion, tags

I'd like to suggest we rename the tag [delta](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta) to [delta-time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-time).

Other than being a Greek letter, and being associated with the concept of 'triangle' (and a load of other things), the term delta is often used to represent a quantity that varies, for instance, "delta x" could represent the difference in a value on the x axis.

It is used in this context when talking about delta-time in a video game: the time that has passed since last frame.

My point is that simply using the term 'delta' is too vague, and to use 'delta' to tag what is actually 'delta-time' is not precise enough. Even Wikipedia has a page for [delta-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this tag is even useful. What does it mean to be an "expert in delta time?" As of now there are only three questions using the tag, and all of them are well-covered by higher level tags, I think.

I think we should add the tag to our [useless tag list](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).

Comment: Is _"expert in [tag label]"_ the proper way to see what a tag is for on SE? If it's the case, well, you're right, maybe we should stop using it.

Comment: It's a useful guideline; tags are for search, and you'd want to make things searchable along axes that users filtering the question list will actually use. That tends to mean tags should focus on potential areas-of-expertise, and tags that don't generally need a fairly compelling domain-specific reason to stick around.