# Is "actions" a worthwhile tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[actions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/actions) has 14 questions as of this writing. A quick survey of the first few suggest that the tag is being used when people are asking about some kind of cause-and-effect system, e.g., I would like to "do this" when "condition occurs."

Is this really a useful tag? Can you really be an "expert" in actions in the general sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My position, if it wasn't implied strongly enough by my asking the question already, is **no**, we shouldn't have this tag and we should add it to the [bad tags](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted) list.

Comment: Totally not useful.