# Is the 'languages' tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

[languages](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) has 40 questions as of this writing. Is this tag useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over the questions, I'd argue that it's not useful within the context of this site. Questions about "languages" here, based on the 40 question sample pool we have today, are either:

- questions about human or natural languages, which is not really specific to game develop and for which there would be better, more specific tags anyway (mainly, [localization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization), possibly something like [natural-language-parsing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language-parsing) in the future, et cetera).
- questions related to picking a language, which is off-topic.
- questions related to functionality or capability of languages, which is off-topic.
- questions related to the theoretical computer science aspects of programming languages, which are off-topic.

I think this tag is bad and should be removed.