# Is the 'pre-processing' tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

[pre-processing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-processing) has a single question of this writing. Is this tag useful?

Comment: I've removed all occurrences of this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a useful tag at all. Preprocessing is a type of solution, not a specific problem or solution per se. One is not an expert in "preprocessing things" in general, one is an expert at some particular task done with or during pre-processing, and in those cases the more specific tag related to that task should be used.

I think we should blacklist this tag.