# How should we handle the 'inspector' tag and 'unity-*' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [inspector](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inspector) tag mainly seems to exist to refer to the Unity inspector. There are fourteen questions with the tag as of this writing.

As a tag, "inspector" alone is far too broad (not only Unity has a property inspector UI, for example, and it's generally unreasonable for one to be considered an "expert in inspectors").

So the question is, is it worth scoping this tag to Unity by renaming it `unity-inspector`? We have a similar tag for [unity-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor). On the other hand, I don't really see that [unity-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor) adds any significant value that isn't covered by the [unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity) tag already. Certainly a quick scan through [unity-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-editor) seems to indicate the tag is misapplied very often.

What should we do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `unity-editor` or `unity-inspector` add anything significant search-wise, and I think they just muddy up the tag pool.

I propose we link `unity-editor` to `unity` as a synonym and blacklist `inspector` outright.

Comment: I have removed the tag `inspector`.

Comment: Should we delete [tag:customeditor] as well?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I merged it into `unity` this morning, I think that's probably reasonable for now.