# Should we make [unreal-editor] a synonym of [unreal] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Last year](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2150/40264), we've discussed if it would be a good idea to remove the tags `unity-editor` and `inspector` (the latter mainly referring to a tool from Unity) because they did not add anything significant to the site.

As such, `unity-editor` as been defined as a synonym of `unity`, and `inspector` has simply been blacklisted.

Should we do the same thing with [unreal-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal-editor): make it a synonym of [unreal-4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal-4)? Or does it really add value to the site?

At the same time, should the tag [blueprints](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueprints) be kept or should we also make it a synonym of `unreal-4`? I understand that someone could be very knowledgeable with the feature, but it seems like a very specific part of a single engine, and where the search feature of the site would do just about the same job as the tag.

Comment: I am only so very lightly familiar with unreal; I would vote to do the above, but I have to ask, is there such a great difference between the versions of unreal that would warrant specific tags for unreal 4, over (say) unreal 2 and 3?

Comment: If not, it might be a better idea to go with the [tag:unreal] tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is reasonable to alias [unreal-editor](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal-editor) to [unreal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal).

I think [blueprints](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueprints) is worth leaving alone, though, because it's a fairly complex sub-domain of the Unreal ecosystem and I can definitely see a place for a set of users who use Blueprints in Unreal extensively wanting to peruse those questions (and similarly for people who use Unreal exclusively with C++ to want to *hide* them).

Comment: How to tag unreal egine questions considering the lighting,editor, particle system, blueprints.... ?

Comment: @Wildfire You can express combined topics by using more than one tag — eg. including the [tag:lighting] tag with the [tag:unreal] tag to ask about lighting in Unreal.

Comment: I have done this.