# What is so special about unity-networking that it deserves its own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is the [unity-networking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-networking) tag.

Is it so special that it needs its own tag?

The excerpt reads:

> Unity 5.1 introduced a new framework to handle client+server networking, also known as UNet.

And the description is a quote:

> Unity 5.1 has a new and improved Networking system with more flexibility and power than the networking system provided in earlier versions of Unity. It has a lower level NetworkTransport class which is a thin layer above basic sockets and then higher level components which add more useful multiplayer features.

Could questions tagged as such be re-tagged [[unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity), [networking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking)] instead, while keeping the same effect?

We've [merged and blacklisted unity-related tags in the past](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2151/40264).

---

There is also the [unet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unet) tag, which seems to be about exactly the same thing, so the answers here should apply to that tag as well. And we should make one a synonym of the other if it's decided to keep it as a separate tag.

Answer (score 5):

I can see value in having a tag set aside for the particular networking *library/API* used in Unity, which I think is what the [unity-networking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unity-networking) tag is intended to do, judging from its tag description:

> Unity 5.1 introduced a new framework to handle client+server
>   networking, also known as UNet.

There are ways to do [networking](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) in Unity without using Unity's built-in Unity Networking, such as hand-rolling code or using third-party libraries like [photon](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photon) (which itself has a tag) — so it makes sense to be able to tag each of these use cases differently.

Similarly, I expect it would be possible for someone to be an expert in using Unity's networking API without being an expert in networking generally, and vice versa: an expert in networking may not be an expert in the Unity Networking API (or other APIs with their own tags like Photon...)

So tagging a question unity-networking/unet (I think these should be synonyms) says more than "this question is about networking a Unity game," it says "this question is about using *this specific networking API*"

This is analogous to tagging a question about using Unreal's node graph-based scripting system with [unreal](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unreal), [blueprints](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blueprints), rather than the more generic term for that technology, [graphs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs), to say "I need help with this particular tool, not just this class of problem"

If we find the Unity-Networking tag is being used too broadly to refer to networking scenarios not involving Unity's specific API, renaming the tag to something narrower (eg. making it a synonym of [unet](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unet)) may help reduce this temptation.

Comment: Are you suggesting we keep unet and make unity-networking a synonym of it?

Comment: I do think they should be synonyms. Which one becomes the canonical term depends on whether we're finding unity-networking is attracting excessive mis-tagging. I haven't investigated yet whether this is a major problem.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your unity, networking tag solution.