# I have a specific question about [specific-question]

Tags: discussion, tags

[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) has no description and ironically isn't very specific. The 6 questions using the tag don't have any similarities.

Also, if your question *isn't* specific, then it is off-topic or too broad. **Does this make all the other questions on Meta Game Dev SE too broad?** Any good post should *already* be specific.

I request this specific tag to be burninated. It is terribly vague, and lacks practicality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The 6 questions using the tag don't have any similarities.

They are all *about a specific question*, as opposed to about a more general policy.

I don't really think this is a useful tag, though, so I've removed it from the questions that had it.

Answer (score 0):

Well that was very specific and to the point, maybe you should tag this question with [specific-question].

... wait in what context are being specific here?

Yup, I agree, lets get rid of this ... vaguely specific tag!