# Do we really need the 'infinite' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As the title says, do we need the tag [infinite](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite)?

At this moment, the tag has only 15 questions, and no usage definition.

The questions tagged are mostly about infinite 2d games, looping content (background), and procedural generation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think we should black list it as it can be applied to a lot of situations, which are not really connected.

And I don't think anyone is an expert in 'infinite'.

Comment: I agree with this.

Comment: @JoshPetrie All right, I'll take care of it.

Comment: *I don't think anyone is an expert in 'infinite'* - Ramanujan might disagree.

Comment: @MooseBoys He'd have to join us :)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody out of game development context knows what procedural is, i bet newbies will search first for "how to make infinite world map in GameMaker" than "Procedural terrain algorithm C++"

> implying they even do search

Comment: It's not clear to me from this post: do you think we should leave the tag or do we need to remove it? Or replace it?

Comment: I think it should stay, if we remove it, newbies will post questions about "infinite generation" with other unrelated tags, this is the closest we can approach "procedural" to "street language"