# The tag 'units' and us

Tags: discussion, tags

This came up while reviewing the suggested edits queue (for tags).

I'd like to highlight something that has been already written [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted/1738#1738) by user15805.

> [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) is ambiguous as users have asked questions tagged with it that are both about entities (i.e. enemy units) and measurements (e.g. unit conversion).
>
> I also believe it doesn't exactly add much in the way of filtering (i.e. searching for questions that are about units in games (usually contained into a much more major category e.g. strategy games where one expects to find units) and units in physics (physics here is a tag that's enough)).
>
> I recommend deletion.

The alternative would be to decide to keep the tag and focus its scope on the concept of measuring stuff, or keep the tag for the concept of in-game entities, typically in army-related games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have removed all current uses of [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) and added it to the [bad tag list](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).

Answer (score 3):

The quoted text reflects my thoughts about it. We should delete the tag [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units).

Comment: I agree, I can't see a good reason to leave the tag around.

Answer (score 2):

The tag [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) is clearly used ambiguously, and the tag does not offer the kind of benefit or support we usually associate with tags. Furthermore, it does not appear that any of the involved questions would suffer detriment to having the tag removed. We should definitely delete it.

In case others wish to have more information to make a decision, here is some information I was able to pool from the [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) wiki and listed questions:

- The tag is currently only being used on 20 different questions. This seems like a particularly small number to have a dedicated tag for, in the first place. Two of these questions have been closed, one for *"not constructive"*, and one as a *"duplicate"*.
- The interpretation of the tag appears to be roughly split down the middle. Half the questions appear to use the tag in regards to *units of measurement*, half the questions appear to use the tag in regards to *ambiguous game units* such as enemies or texture objects. There is no wiki excerpt detailing the intended use.
- Despite being created 4 years ago, there are currently only 2 views on the tag wiki, one of them being myself in response to this meta. It is clear, from this, that the this tag has not received any real support in regards to meta. Furthermore, there do not appear to be any users subscribed to this tag. Of the top users, I only note a single user who has answered more than one question with this tag,  at a total count of 3.
- The tag is only used as a secondary tag. While it is somewhat clear (in most cases) what the askers intention was, in regards to using the tag on their question, the questions all feature more relevant tag that more accurately categorise the question. Not a single question categorises soley under the [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units) tag.

---

I have previously been told that a good way to judge any *possible* benefit from a tag would be to determine whether somebody *professionally adept* with the subject would be more likely to provide good quality answers. Ultimately, I do not believe you can be a professional in regards to units of measurement *or* game units, as either topic is simply to ambiguous.

Comment: Agreed. The closest thing I can think of to an expert in "units" would be someone well-versed in working with & converting between coordinate systems, for which we have the [tag:coordinates] tag. I think that and physics covers most interesting uses of units of measurement for gamedev purposes.