# Sizing up the 'size' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Similar to the context of "[The tag 'units' and us](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2246/the-tag-units-and-us)", I came across the tag [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size), through processing a review queue<sup>1</sup>. Ultimately, I initially meant to use this tag, but a bit of investigation lead me to the assumption that I *probably* shouldn't.

This tag does not appear to have been brought up in meta, previously, but it appears to suffer the same problems we see with the tag [units](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/units): the tag receives little attention, and when it does, the interpreted context of "size" appears to be mixed.

What should we do to improve the quality issues concerning the [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) tag?

<sub><sup>1</sup>In not *exactly* the same context, of course, but I digress.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this tag should be deleted.** The tag is neither popular, nor useful, due to ambiguity. For what little benefit it adds, as a tag, the use of *other* tags serve the related questions in greater quality.

---

The intention of the tag appears *very* ambiguous, from inspection of the questions that use it. The main subject of each question varies, and with it, the exact context of "size". The context is actually usually found in the tag that precedes [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size), but I feel that for this very reason, the 'size context' tag should be more than enough.

- [perspective](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perspective) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used in a question asking about the difference in game object size as a direct result of player perspective.
- [texture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/texture) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used a couple of times in questions asking about the physical texture sizes.
- [scale](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used in a question asking about best practices for scaling the size of game objects.
- [file](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file) and [file-format](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-format) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used in relation to questions concerning the actual file size of the end build, or impacts on said file size relating to various used file formats.
- [font](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used in questions relating to both font size and the size of UI as a result of changes to font size.
- [screen](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen) and [camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) has been used in questions relating to the screen size, both physical, and in terms of the projection made by the in-game camera.

---

Apart from that, it appears that the tag is not very popular:

- The tag has been used on 20 differant questions, 3 of which have been closed as "primarily opinion-based", "unrelated to game-developing" and "unclear".
- The tag has no apparent followers, and the top users have all only answered a single question.
- The tag ***has*** been used, recently, with a single question tagged with [size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/size) in the last 30 days.
- As mentioned, the tag has no guidance wiki, and the tag appears to be used quite ambiguously. Keep in mind that even if we decide on proper usage of this tag, the resulting cleanup would easily remove *at least* half of the questions that use this tag. We simply do not have the question count to warrant needing it.

Comment: I have burninated the size tag; you can accept this answer.