# What's the point of the [class] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that someone had proposed an edit that added the [class](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class) tag to a question. The tag has no description and it looks like it's used for when the question relates to the generic programming concept "class".

Should the tag be removed? Is this actually a useful tag? If it is, could a usage description be added to the tag wiki?

It feels slightly weird to have a tag as such, almost like tagging questions involving functions with [function](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) and variables with [variable](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[class](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class) has about 17 uses as of this writing, but I agree it's not particularly useful. In all 17 cases it seems to either add no value, or seems like a more conceptually-specific tag could replace it.

I'd be in favor of nuking it.