# Can we please burn the "environment" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

My arguments for burning [environment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environment) with fire are:

1. No description of the tag.
2. It has been used only 6 times since 2013.
3. In those 6 questions, they have been used with a wide approach, meaning either the development environment, or the game's environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing it seems reasonable to me. I can't think of a way to codify the tag's use that would not be better served by making the tag name itself slightly longer and more descriptive.

Comment: I've removed all occurrences of the tag and added it to the bad tags list.