# Do we really need a "free" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As in the title, do we *really* need a [free](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) tag? What is the utility thereof?

Comment: I was thinking of asking the same question.

Comment: I have removed the tag from all the questions, and added it to the blacklist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, we don't need the [free](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/free) tag.

- In my opinion, this is a meta tag which does not inform at all about the topic of the question.
- You can't be an expert in free.
- The vast majority of the 24 questions with this tag are closed. This is associated to the fact that questions about 'free' stuff are most of the time off-topic/too broad for this site. (E.g. asking for free resources.)

I think we should remove it and add it to the blacklist.

Comment: Why remove the free tag? It could mean free-to-play.

Comment: @narawagames There is the [tag:free-to-play] for that purpose :) And as for 'why', the answer answers just that.