# Should we alias programming to "programming-theory" or "software-engineering?" Or...?

Tags: discussion, tags

Per the recent discussions at [What's the point of the tag [programming]?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/whats-the-point-of-the-tag-programming) the consensus on the [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag is that we'll keep it, but heavily re-scope it to try and focus more on theoretical and process-oriented topics.

To that end, I'd like to create some tag synonyms, but I don't believe that "programming" is appropriate as the target of those synonyms, because I don't think it helps convey the new, narrower scope.

What should we call the target of "programming?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We should call it `software-engineering`; fundamentally the scope of the tag is similar to that of the [Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): methods and practices of building software (games, specifically), including the theoretical.

Comment: There is already a [tag:software-engineering] tag. In the case this answer is the most popular, I guess you'd only create a tag synonym.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do. The meaningful distinction between the software engineering tag and the new scope of the programming tag is almost nil, imo.

Comment: But if we read the description of the `software-engineering` tag, it seems quite different from what `programming` currently covers...

Comment: Currently covers, yes, but it seems pretty inline with what I think the new scope of the programming tag _should_ cover.

Comment: If we go with this, we should consider keeping `programming` as an alias. In my experience with students and recent grads, I don't think anyone has asked me about becoming a "software-engineer" as opposed to a "programmer". So I expect, while they may mean software-engineering, they're more likely to use the programming tag and not find software-engineering with out that alias.

Comment: @Chris Right, that's what this is proposing. When a user types the "programming" tag on a question, it will get replaced with whatever alias we end up selecting as a result of this meta question.

Comment: I have now done this.

Answer (score 2):

We should call it `programming-theory`, as originally suggested. It is succinct, and not terribly dissimilar from the current `programming` tag, so users will be less surprised by the tag system replacing it for them when they type `programming`.

Comment: I don't like this for two reasons: "programming theory" isn't really a thing, and it implies computer science rather than software engineering.

Answer (score 1):

This mega post contains all the questions that have the tag [software-engineering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-engineering). Since the merge of the tag [programming](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming), some of these don't really need the tag `software-engineering` as the scope is different, so all of these questions tags should be revised.

The idea is that whenever you have time to review a couple of them, review them (either retag the questions or leave them as is, as needed), and then remove the questions from this list.

Once all the questions have been reviewed, we'll be able to delete this post.

1. [Is storing all game objects in a single list an acceptable design?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/22559)
2. [Throwing Exceptions in C++ game DLL's? Pros and Cons](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2762)
3. [Are there cases where globals/singletons are useful in game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2766)
4. [Finding other programmers to help on a project](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2791)
5. [Asset Library Class or passing Asset's through constructors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128125)
6. [Implementing behavior in a simple adventure game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23172)
7. [What is wrong with my Item collection/Itemcounter Script](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128452)
8. [Are AAA games still made with programming languages?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128501)
9. [What basic non-games related computer knowledge should a games programmer possess?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23459)
10. [Keybindings in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48064)
11. [Software engineering theory for hobbyist developers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/24410)
12. [What's the best phone for game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5288)
13. [Converting DirectX 9 code to DirectX 10](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5640)
14. [How do I update individual sprites within a spritegroup in pygame?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/103883)
15. [Finite state machine in C++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6005)
16. [How are the same items generated with slightly different attributes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131232)
17. [Why do most games save the players team as a short int in the player class and not as a pointer to a team object?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51270)
18. [opengl memory issue - quite strange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7457)
19. [Event-driven Communication in a Game Engine: Yes or No?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7718)
20. [Is Test Driven Development viable in game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7727)
21. [Technical differences between square and hexagon for a grid?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/76108)
22. [Does C# have a future in games development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7956)
23. [What are the Starting Games I need to make?[Best steps for a beginner Game Developer?]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8010)
24. [How do I implement a racing clock that shows elapsed time?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27744)
25. [How to set HUD elements position and size depending of resolution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/77753)
26. [How to rotate a surface in pygame, without changing its shape](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/133887)
27. [Quantity of dropped/spawned items in container](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134223)
28. [How to handle a player's level and its consequent privileges?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/54758)
29. [Decoupling the entity from whatever controls it](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/80334)
30. [Representing a high-resolution deformable solid in 3D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134780)
31. [Selecting Dictionary item based on custom classes instead of keys](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109335)
32. [Design patterns in Game Physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29556)
33. [How to write "Hello World" for N64 purely from scratch?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/80909)
34. [What is the point in using API such as Open GL or DirectX when there are game engines?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/80912)
35. [How should I design an easing class in C++?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/135626)
36. [Effective methods to continuously update movement in a tower defense game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10921)
37. [Game companies - Involvement of programmers in the design process](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10999)
38. [How can I run a .jar file with XNA?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30148)
39. [How should bots be recognised in a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30191)
40. [Getting player cube to move left or right in relation to camera based on camera's rotation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/135907)
41. [How do I implement a programming system in my game that is both accessible, powerful, and fast to code in?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56473)
42. [Implementing a wait function in a game script](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56611)
43. [Best way to gain C++ working experience for a job in games (coming from C#)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56619)
44. [Game programming course materials: What should it include?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30647)
45. [Newbie game programmer - Where do I start?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56772)
46. [Conceptual question regarding Belief-Desire-Intent agent](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/110711)
47. [Should our group try to make a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/11814)
48. [Cocos2d Sprite 3D position](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111082)
49. [How to make "Shaky mouse cursor" Before shoot the target Like in a Dart Game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111244)
50. [How do i get my tilemap to move at the same speed as my character](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12769)
51. [Implementing a FSM with ActionScript 2 without using classes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/31698)
52. [What's the difference between a "Gameplay Programmer" and a "Gameplay Engineer?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58240)
53. [Mobile Multiplayer games and coping with high latency](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58450)
54. [Trophies programming design pattern](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13288)
55. [Confused about this Timer function C++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/112189)
56. [Why should I write a computer program if I don't know exactly how the program gets run in its entirety?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58661)
57. [How can I create an extending chain like the hookshot in Zelda in Unity?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58686)
58. [How can I move and rotate an object in an “infinity” or “figure 8” trajectory?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138165)
59. [Entity Component System based engine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/32582)
60. [Turn a single player game into multiplayer game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138724)
61. [Snake game made in processing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138769)
62. [How to implement mutable functionality at runtime?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138774)
63. [How to make minecraft like world round?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59273)
64. [How to create a text-based game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59274)
65. [How would I go about programming atmosphere for a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59278)
66. [Trying to use yield to wait for a few seconds to avoid the sounds from Interfering with each other](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/112965)
67. [How can I maintain a rectangular formation when units are added or removed?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59647)
68. [Will there be any more books in the Game Programming Gems series?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/59864)
69. [Problem with Collision Detection](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113561)
70. [Networking in a strategy, city management game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139527)
71. [Does an indie game developer really need to know graphics programming beyond the basics?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15202)
72. [What language for Indie dev?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15344)
73. [Manage a large number of independent actors in real-time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15408)
74. [Making a game for multiple platforms](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/60365)
75. [Passing data between engine layers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/60378)
76. [Calculate speed vehicle physics 2d racegame](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140631)
77. [How to implement auto-aiming / auto-targeting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/35221)
78. [I have a game based on combining 2 ingredients to create a product. What is the best way to code this? (Unity)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141111)
79. [Are there such things as online development projects?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/89644)
80. [Generate planet like heightmaps](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/89655)
81. [Which programming language should I start with in game dev?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115726)
82. [What exactly is a 'set of states'?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116228)
83. [How to to convert UV coordinates to texel coordinates and how to convert texel coordinates to "array coordinates"?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/90289)
84. [Is it essential that I learn Try/Catch and Finally statements for Game Programming, or is it something I can come back to?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/17812)
85. [What can I do to make sure that I have the energy to work on my game while working full-time?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/17916)
86. [Engine programming, is it supposed to be enjoyable?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18145)
87. [Little and big endianness in games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37712)
88. [How can be data oriented programming applied for GUI system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37797)
89. [Tangible benefits to speed-coding your personal game projects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18469)
90. [RPGMakerVX - Changing item_max?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/38662)
91. [Why are games built on cross-platform engines sometimes exclusive to Windows?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/144584)
92. [Check if an object is facing another based on angles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/19619)
93. [Make an object slide around an obstacle](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/19621)
94. [Map editor undo function - Not actually setting values to tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66079)
95. [What are some great papers/publications relating to game programming?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20106)
96. [Are there places in the gaming industry for people who are artistic and programmers?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/95285)
97. [How or why are major video games programmed so reliably?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66865)
98. [3D Location Handling](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20438)
99. [Rotating a 3rd person camera toward a target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/96967)
100. [Limitations of p2p multiplayer games vs client-server](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67738)
101. [the basic or important thing that i need to learn from C#](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67799)
102. [Where can a game developer/programmer get freelance jobs?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/121361)
103. [Computer Games Technolgy or Software Engineering?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44667)
104. [Showing range on hexagonal grid](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/45063)
105. [For Indie Developers should abstraction or development speed be prioritized?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/122029)
106. [Game-oriented programming language features/objectives/paradigm?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5192)
107. [How should I proceed next with my programming skills?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20993)
108. [How do bullets work in video games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/124734)
109. [How should I handle functions, where two classes have equal use?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21226)
110. [How to handle game states for a single-player / multiplayer game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/728)
111. [Cross platform low level graphic API](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/731)
112. [How should I check if a player has completed an achievement?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21502)
113. [naming conventions in game code / vocabulary](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21520)
114. [Should each UI screen contain the list of screens on the stack or should I use a manager class?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21570)
115. [What properties should be private, public, and protected?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125655)
116. [Is there any potential downside to procedurally programmingh in DirectX 11, without classes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46094)
117. [How do the Box2d and Bullet physics simulations work internally?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1626)
118. [OpenAL - alGetSourcei and AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED gives junk](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1629)
119. [Best solution for "level string"?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1799)
120. [How do I generate surface normals?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1882)
121. [Expandable 2d environment by spawning and controlling individual tiles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/70593)
122. [Experiences of test-driven devleopment in large projects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1905)
123. [making a game in 2D(C++). SDL or openGL? Or, why not both?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46698)
124. [What should every graphics programmer write](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2329)
125. [Clickable hex grid in c#.net](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2338)
126. [Atmospheric Scattering](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2351)
127. [How do I detect UI button presses on Android](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/126579)
128. [C++: Smart pointers, Raw pointers, No Pointers?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2578)
129. [How do videogames store information offscreen?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/127762)
130. [Are there any clever methods of regulating bandwidth usage for voice chat payload packets?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2727)
131. [Does Big O really matter?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3374)
132. [Level Implementation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3776)
133. [What will AMD Fusion or likewise hybrid CPU/GPU will change for the 3D programmer ? Are they potentially faster?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3808)
134. [Get Facebook Picture in Cocos2d-iphone V3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72527)
135. [What are some programming design patterns that are useful in game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4157)
136. [What do gameplay programmers do?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73271)
137. [Match-3 Shuffle Required?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73288)
138. [What scripting language would you recommend for a C++ game project?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4682)
139. [Simple game engines / development tools made with artists in mind?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4691)
140. [Vehicle audio recording](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129998)
141. [What should I consider when evaluating libraries, engines and frameworks for making a game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/49869)
142. [Arc'd jumping method?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5724)
143. [What are the advantages of having component logic in a "system" versus the component itself?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/74312)
144. [Do "write once run anywhere" engines require platform specific code for multiplayer?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50402)
145. [Subscriber with many publishers: unsubscribing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/104022)
146. [Deep copying or cloning in actionscript 3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50627)
147. [Where do i start with game development when i'm terrible at art and 3d modelling?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131394)
148. [Problem with Update(GameTime) Methods and Pause implementation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26222)
149. [Recent mainstream games written in pure C? not C++ what was/is the point?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26399)
150. [Cyclic Dependencies](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6857)
151. [What are the restrictions of 3g online games](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6967)
152. [What tools should I consider if my aim is to make a game available to as many platforms as possible?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6975)
153. [Is there a 3d animation software that prioritizes working with code rather than GUI?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51141)
154. [Unity - protect MonoBehaviour-derived classes from instantiating via new in C#](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/132084)
155. [What can I do to avoid one-off flags and checks throughout my code?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/105068)
156. [Are interleaved vertex data formats better than non-interleaved formats?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51648)
157. [Amount of Data Calculated in a Game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/105549)
158. [Game Development Resources?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27351)
159. [What should a game engine do?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7870)
160. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/133323
161. [Low coupling and tight cohesion](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8899)
162. [What's next to learn?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8985)
163. [Unity PhotonView - Ownership problems when synching objects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/107950)
164. [Finding the intersection of a plane and a ray](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134062)
165. [Is video compositing feasible?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/79485)
166. [Game programming books?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/54615)
167. [Why is 3D game development supposed to be so hard?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/28680)
168. [How much memory usage is too much in a Flash game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9495)
169. [Adaptive Characters: AI Solution Needs a Problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9500)
170. [Beat detection and FFT](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9761)
171. [Making game constants/tables available to game logic classes/routines in a modular manner](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9781)
172. [What do I need to consider before making any class singleton?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134981)
173. [Game Maker (and others): what data type is colour and how can I compare them?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134985)
174. [What is "tools development?"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/55690)
175. [Pointers in C# Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109464)
176. [How to find if an object is facing another object given position and direction as separate vectors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109513)
177. [Networking/Packet Design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/110160)
178. [Are there games with player programmable vehicle control behaviour?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/110544)
179. [Trying to create a UE4 blueprint or script to recognize set shapes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136330)
180. [What research areas exist in game programming?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/11615)
181. [Mouse location is off due to camera](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12442)
182. [How to do collision detection on marching cubes terrain?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83143)
183. [Networking gampeplay - Sending controller inputs vs. sending game actions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58129)
184. [How could you parallelise a 2D boids simulation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14369)
185. [Stopping Animations For Player In Java Using Slick2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113299)
186. [Can't parent the standard FPSController during gameplay](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113310)
187. [How to make a "Camera" in Java](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113319)
188. [Organizing platformer game into classes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14898)
189. [How can I get textures on edge of walls like in Super Metroid and Aquaria?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15302)
190. [Stat Multipliers: from Base Value or Iterative](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/87528)
191. [Andengine onAreaTouched TouchEvent not working - ACTION_OUTSIDE & ACTION_CANCEL](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/87541)
192. [Pickup another book or submerge into XNA](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16203)
193. [Should I use a visual tool or code myself?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/61145)
194. [Help for structuring classes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115241)
195. [At which school levels do you learn to make games form scratch?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115460)
196. [Efficient 2d Java Line of Sight for a lot of entities?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/17218)
197. [When should I acquire game objects with dependency injection, find-with-tag, or singletons?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/142024)
198. [VS deployment problems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18228)
199. [It is worth adding 'futuristic' features to our game, or should we put our focus elsewhere?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/19064)
200. [What are some good game programming short courses?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/19331)
201. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/118652
202. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40449
203. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40529
204. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40604
205. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66553
206. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/41898
207. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/41937
208. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/42057
209. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/147593
210. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44043
211. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44053
212. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44513
213. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44530
214. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44561
215. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/121303
216. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/68547
217. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44718
218. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/124643
219. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/339
220. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69797
221. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/70003
222. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1460
223. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1500
224. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21842
225. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21861
226. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/22131
227. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/22356
228. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2184
229. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2194
230. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/47074
231. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/127781
232. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/127951
233. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/71811
234. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128330
235. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128365
236. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/101169
237. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/23608
238. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72365
239. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/72376
240. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/128824
241. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/101814
242. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48426
243. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/24195
244. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/24199
245. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129619
246. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/49130
247. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130089
248. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5439
249. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5530
250. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/25633
251. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5785
252. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/5800
253. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131396
254. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/104397
255. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6796
256. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51044
257. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26779
258. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/75595
259. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/75678
260. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26941
261. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27071
262. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/132477
263. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27442
264. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27459
265. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53094
266. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53095
267. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8195
268. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8234
269. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8475
270. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8485
271. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8490
272. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/78032
273. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/133934
274. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/54670
275. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/28714
276. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/80092
277. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9985
278. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10003
279. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10013
280. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134846
281. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/134908
282. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29384
283. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/55497
284. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/10373
285. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/81053
286. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29766
287. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/29790
288. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136463
289. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12883
290. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13877
291. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/84239
292. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/32980
293. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33007
294. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113465
295. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113517
296. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113521
297. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/60065
298. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15460
299. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/87319
300. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15792
301. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15989
302. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16023
303. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115053
304. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/61356
305. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/89719
306. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/17414
307. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/62510
308. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/36014
309. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37581
310. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/117631
311. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/19529
312. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/119055
313. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146700
314. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/96039
315. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/147882
316. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44954
317. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/124359
318. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69134
319. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/892
320. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21711
321. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/21997
322. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/98692
323. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2029
324. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/2116
325. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/126426
326. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/126438
327. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/71022
328. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3146
329. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3186
330. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48436
331. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48446
332. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/102487
333. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73097
334. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4863
335. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/103240
336. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/74611
337. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/74647
338. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/131032
339. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/50306
340. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26712
341. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/132445
342. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7521
343. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53282
344. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/8691
345. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/54847
346. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/54851
347. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108641
348. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/55249
349. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/55518
350. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/135422
351. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/135441
352. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/81263
353. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56064
354. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56189
355. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/11417
356. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56670
357. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/82281
358. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12088
359. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/82572
360. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12269
361. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12272
362. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111730
363. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/58033
364. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13162
365. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111922
366. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111969
367. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/112025
368. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/83676
369. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14220
370. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14233
371. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/84604
372. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113163
373. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14421
374. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139070
375. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33118
376. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/86115
377. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139434
378. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113762
379. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/113881
380. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/34074
381. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15682
382. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15708
383. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15729
384. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/15735
385. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/34194
386. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/34231
387. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140286
388. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/87860
389. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/140719
390. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/61619
391. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16636
392. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16640
393. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/61770
394. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/35666
395. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37503
396. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/91958
397. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18259
398. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18867
399. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/64094
400. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/38814
401. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/64570
402. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/64625
403. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/41982
404. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/42009
405. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/42015
406. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66691
407. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/43651
408. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/43929
409. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/121492
410. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/123712
411. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/97320
412. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/414
413. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/854
414. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69582
415. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/69615
416. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125099
417. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/98267
418. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/1290
419. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125707
420. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/125964
421. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46424
422. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/46979
423. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/47354
424. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3969
425. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3980
426. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/3987
427. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/48535
428. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/73192
429. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/129906
430. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/4967
431. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130443
432. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130449
433. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130766
434. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130835
435. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/104098
436. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6193
437. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6237
438. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/6566
439. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/75315
440. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7334
441. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7591
442. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7611
443. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/7633
444. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53151
445. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/27666
446. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/53966
447. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/9187
448. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108492
449. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108542
450. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/55389
451. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/81604
452. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/56390
453. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/30860
454. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/12205
455. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136839
456. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/57603
457. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/111384
458. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13193
459. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13535
460. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/138098
461. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14092
462. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/84490
463. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33062
464. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/14767
465. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33339
466. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/33644
467. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/114823
468. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/35722
469. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116030
470. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/62772
471. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/116423
472. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18051
473. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/117104
474. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/63403
475. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/38251
476. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/64022
477. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/144609
478. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/95543
479. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/66881
480. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/146795
481. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/67172
482. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/43504
483. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/43505
484. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44768
485. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44835
486. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/121662
487. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/124225

???

1. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/37645