# Do we need the tag [middleware]?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've recently decided to [get rid of the `engine` tag](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2391/40264), along [with `api`, `framework`, `libraries` and `sdk`](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/weve-blacklisted-engine-should-we-do-the-same-for-the-other-similar-tags).

I haven't noticed before but we also have a tag for [middleware](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middleware), where the description is appropriate, but that has no tag usage.

Like the other tags, I feel this tag does not bring value to the site and is more a meta-tag than anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree; we should blacklist this tag like we are doing with the others you cited in the original question.

Comment: There were ten questions with this tag. 8 of them were closed, or ended up closed after I looked at them. The only two remaining didn't even really need the tag, so I removed it. The tag is now blacklisted.

Comment: You should include that in your answer.

Comment: @Tommy I never include these kinds of comments about the actions taken in response to a meta post in the post itself, even if it's my own post, because I want to keep a distinction between what was proposed and what was implemented, primarily for clarity in what was voted on and when.