# Do we need the [old-school] tag?

Tags: discussion

Do we need the [old-school](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-school) tag? Current stats: 24 question & 7 followers.

Comment: You should mark Josh's answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's a meta-tag describing the domain of the question or an ideal goal of the project the question pertains to.

It should be burninated.

Comment: I've done this.

Answer (score -3):

I think we should keep it, but refine it's usage, then rename it.

Questions with the [old-school](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-school) mainly deal with

- Old hardware
- Reproduction of visual and audio effects older games had
- Historical questions about old games and how they were made.

I think we should keep the tag on the questions which relate to the graphics and audio styles as seen in the old-school games (just like we have a tag for [pixel-art](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pixel-art)), and remove it from the other types of questions.

Then perhaps we should find a better name that reflects it, such as `old-school-effect` or `old-school-style`.

Comment: What is *old hardware* or *older games*? I would not define PlayStation, or some partially-early Windows games to be considered, for example. However, I know that others *would*. I feel this tag is too broad for this suggested used. Unless, of course, we can reach a concencus of period (say, "pre-2000"). But then, how do you handle the future? Does it stay at "pre-2000", or does it become "pre-2001" next year, and "pre-2002", the year after?

Comment: @Gnemlock With the amount of questions that would be tagged as such, I don't think there would be much trouble managing it. And I would not use years, but maybe more which consoles would fit the description, so the description would stay constant, without needing to update it year after year.