# Why is there no [boo] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a couple of questions relating to Boo, and they're tagged with [scripting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting).

Can we re-tag them with [boo](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boo), or the tag has been removed for a reason not written here and should not be re-introduced?

Comment: <Tongue in cheek> Because no one uses Boo.

Comment: You can take your tongue out of your cheek, that's pretty true. Unity has even removed support for it.

Comment: @Byte56 Just wanted my comment to be clear that I wasn't being *entirely* serious. I'm sure someone somewhere LOVES programming in Boo.

Comment: Ghosts, for example. I'll show myself out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no [boo](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boo) simply because noone has created one.

If I had to speculate, I would say that the absence of this tag may have actually *led* to users using more generic tags, such as [scripting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting). This seems to be further supported by the fact that all [scripting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) questions that reference *"boo"* were created by new users.

The logical thing to do, here, is simply create a [boo](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boo) tag. It is a tag pertaining to a specific programming language that *is* used in game development, no matter how uncommon. There is no reason why such a tag would be blacklisted, [and it isn't](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).