# Is the tag [techniques] useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yes, we have a tag [techniques](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techniques).

It has no tag description and no tag usage and it is used on a very broad range of topics (as broad as 15 questions can be).

Is it a meta-tag that can be used for everything and anything and should be removed/blacklisted, or should we fix it?

Comment: I wonder whether once upon a time the tag might have been intended to refer to a "technique" in the sense of a shader, ie. a piece of data representing a collection of passes and render states that should be applied together to achieve a particular effect.

Comment: @DMGregory it could have been applied to that, yes; I guess a description should have been added right away to avoid any confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not see any non-meta use for the tag [techniques](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techniques). In fact, it is so clearly being used as a meta tag in all of the current usages, I am already going to start removing it from questions.

In any situation where we are asking about "techniques", assuming the question is *not* too broad, we are asking about the techniques in a *very* specific context; that context already tells us what the *actual* tag should be. You do *not* have an "expert" in "technique".

The tag should be removed and blacklisted.

Comment: I'll accept once all the tags have been removed, but I guess you could start right away :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt, it is done.