# Whither the Update tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today we have a tag for [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) with no usage guidance yet.

It's not very popular (only 64 questions), and seems to be used for a mix of topics:

- How to use the **game update loop pattern**

  - [Changing the current state of an entity in the middle of an update step or wait for the end?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140308/changing-the-current-state-of-an-entity-in-the-middle-of-an-update-step-or-wait)
  - [How do I pass my objects to the update method?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134705/how-do-i-pass-my-objects-to-the-update-method)
  - [Is it safe to base a combo system in frames instead of time?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120646/is-it-safe-to-base-a-combo-system-in-frames-instead-of-time)
- How to **modify a particular piece of data** over time / over a network

  - [How to correctly update sprite rect](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/140431/how-to-correctly-update-sprite-rect)
  - [MMO Player Position Update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/144760/mmo-player-position-update)
  - [Data overwritten in MapSubresource() method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133125/data-overwritten-in-mapsubresource-method)
- How to use the **MonoBehaviour message called "Update"** in Unity

  - [Update function only running once](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142910/update-function-only-running-once)
  - [base.Update() makes coroutine stop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136995/base-update-makes-coroutine-stop)
  - [2D Game has very bad lag because of one script?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/112230/2d-game-has-very-bad-lag-because-of-one-script)
- How to **deploy game software updates to players**, or modify games on distribution platforms

  - [Game launcher / updater download delta diff](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/138622/game-launcher-updater-download-delta-diff)
  - [Unity, Steam and updaters!](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/123998/unity-steam-and-updaters)
  - [Declaring another alpha or beta testing after a game app for Android (APK file) is uploaded and already published in Google Play Store](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/declaring-another-alpha-or-beta-testing-after-a-game-app-for-android-apk-file)

It doesn't look like the current version of this tag is clearly identifying a particular topic or area of expertise.

Should we delete it outright, modify it to focus on one specific topic, or cleave it into distinct topic tags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) is not clear enough and should be deleted.

However, while doing so, the questions tagged with [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) regarding the topic **game update loop pattern** could be tagged with [game-loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-loop) instead, while those with the topic **deploy game software updates to players** could be retagged with [deployment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment). I feel the other two topics you've covered are using [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) as a meta tag.

Comment: I agree with this, except that I think questions about "deploying game software updates" could be better served by the "deployment" tag. I'd rather not see "software-engineering" turn into (more of) a catch-all.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Good catch, I did not know we had a deployment tag. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Finally got around to removing all of the [tag:update] tags. :) Found a few more candidates for tag cleanup in the process, but that can be a problem for another day... ;)

Comment: @DMGregory Great job! Make sure to update the [blacklisted tag list](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).

Answer (score 1):

I think the **update loop** and **deploying game updates** uses of the tag both identify a specific problem domain in which someone could develop particular expertise.

The update loop questions can use the existing tag [game-loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-loop).

Deploying game updates would need a new tag, something like `software-updates` to distinguish the subject from runtime updates of in-game data.

---

I think the "modify a piece of data" use of the tag is purely meta and should be removed. I don't think someone can be an expert in "modifying data" alone.

I think tagging a question "Update" because it entails a method *named* `Update()` is pure noise, and the tag should be replaced with [game-loop](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-loop) if the question is really about simulating behaviour over time via updates, or simply deleted otherwise.