# Made a mistake with the replication tag

Tags: support, tags

I was following up on an [earlier thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/whither-the-update-tag), removing & replacing the [update](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) tag on questions, when I came across a question about "updating" positions of players to one another in an MMO.

"That's replication" I thought, so I tried replacing it with a [replication](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) tag, discovering to my surprise that we didn't already have one, so a new tag was created.

After giving the new tag a quick description:

> Replication is the process of synchronizing game state across multiple
>   devices, so actions that one player takes in a multiplayer game are
>   accurately presented to all other players. Replication includes
>   strategies to minimize and hide communication latency and resolve
>   outcomes where multiple players interact, such as shooting or
>   attempting to move into the same location.

...I found the [synchronization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) tag, which covers the same topic:

> A process of maintaining similar game state across players and/or
>   servers, thus giving all players same info about current sutuation on
>   playfield.

I'm not able to turn my accidentally-created [replication](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replication) into a synonym of [synchronization](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) since I don't have any rep with that tag.

What's the recommended solution for me to fix my redundant tag? Should I just wait for it to age out of the system with 0 posts, or mark its description to point users at the correct synchronization tag instead, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, tags with 0 question and that don't have synonym will be deleted after one day.

I guess asking your question here can be interpreted as "should we make it as a synonym?". I'd say "yes", if a mod spots this question before the tag dies on its own, it could make sense to add a synonym to make the first tag easier to spot.

I don't think modifying the description of `synchronization` is the right thing to do; a tag should stand on its own. The tag synonym infrastructure is there for that reason.