# Are the tags "concept" and "conceptual" useful here?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, I noticed the tag [conceptual](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conceptual) applied to [a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/158047/is-there-any-known-game-which-has-been-created-to-grant-true-happiness-to-its-pl). I was surprised to discover that other questions have this tag applied, because it seems like a meta-tag.

The handful of questions in the tag interpret it rather loosely. Should we clarify/synonymize or delete this tag (and related tags like [concept](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept), which don't yet exist but could easily be pre-emptively captured in this discussion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that this tag adds any value as-is; I am personally in favor of adding it to the blacklist.

I can't see a useful path towards clarifying it. The obvious attempt, "game-concepts," seems like just another way to say [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) except that it invites opinion-based questions like "here's my game concept, what do you think?" which aren't on-topic here.

The tag is often used in a way that seems to simply categorize the question, as in "I don't actually *have* this problem, I'm just thinking about the problem *conceptually*." It's not useful in that context.

Consequently, I think it should be removed.

Comment: I was thinking of posting the same. The most constructive uses of it seem to be "please explain this concept" which could as easily be "please explain this term" under the [tag:terminology] tag. I don't think conceptual adds anything beyond what our other tags cover.

Comment: Failing any real opposition and having at least some moderate support, I'm going to start removing these today.

Comment: ...and it is done.