# is the tag [surface] useful?

Tags: discussion

The [surface](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface) "seems to be a mish-mash of questions about DirectX Surface data structures, supporting Microsoft Surface tablet computer hardware, vector algebra involving planes, and contact with the skin of an object."

Currently, it has been applied to 23 questions & has no posted guidance.
The idea of being an "expert in surfaces" (at least with respect to certain definitions) seems awkward in a way that suggests it might be meta.

So, for community discussion: is the [surface](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surface) tag useful, and if so, how to we want to apply it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Glancing at the question list, it seems to me like it is a meta tag.

The only usefulness I'd see would be about its usage on questions about "Microsoft Surface" (the device) because we have questions about [ipad](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ipad) and such, but, thanks to DMGregory who spotted it, we only have about [one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141394/how-to-support-surface-pens-in-unity) question asking about this.

Tags that are attached to only one question are stripped from the question by the system after some time.

Thus, the tag appears useless and could/should be removed and probably added to our [blacklist](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted).

Comment: Cool. Should I start removing the tags or is this something better left to diamond studded mods?

Comment: @Pikalek You can go ahead :)

Comment: “Tags that are attached to only one question are stripped from the question by the system after some time.” — note: only if the tag has no description. (thankfully that's the case here)

Comment: @doppelgreener that's good to know!

Comment: @Vaillancourt I just finished removing the last batch of surface tags, not sure if anything special needs to be done with the tag itself...

Comment: @Pikalek thanks! Maybe just adding it to [the list here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted) would be the last step!

Comment: @Vaillancourt Done, thanks for reminding me about the meta-list!